# Add text of cell range in one cell in Excel

Tags: excel, string-concatenation

I want to concatenate a range of cells into one cell, without macros/vbscript.

The formula `CONCATENATE()` gets individual cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not that easy, but I end up with a solution that works wonders!

`A1`: the text to search

`B1:BN`: The range within the results would go

`B5`: The delimiter text

```
=MID($A$1,LEN(CONCAT($B$1:B1))+COUNTA($B$1:B1)*LEN($B$5)+1,
    SEARCH(
        $B$5,
        $A$1,
        LEN(
           CONCAT($B$1:B1)) + COUNTA($B$1:B1)*LEN($B$5)+1)
           -(LEN(CONCAT($B$1:B1))+COUNTA($B$1:B1)*LEN($B$5)+1))
```

As for now it works perfect. Note that you can use whatever text as delimiter. In my case it was "comma + space".

Where Concat is a simple function that concatenates a range of cells:

```
Function Concat(myRange As Range) As String
  Dim r As Range
  Application.Volatile
  For Each r In myRange
    If Len(r.Text) Then
      Concat = Concat & IIf(Concat <> "", "", "") & r.Text
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `CONCATENATE()` or `&` to join cells. There is no range you can grab all at once unless you use a UDF such as [`MCONCAT`](https://ms-office.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-mconcat-function-microsoft-excel-359835/).